# What configuration changes needed on tcServer to work with Apache Web server

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.2, mod-jk

I have Apache Webserver 2.2.17 and tcServer-6.0.20 and I want to dispatch requests from apache to tcserver.

I am using mod_jk.so and I have the following in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

<IfModule jk_module>
   JkWorkersFile /x/y/apache2/conf/workers.properties
   JkLogFile /x/y/apache2/logs/mod_jk.log
   JkLogLevel info
   JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
   JkMount /xyz/* ww
</IfModule>
```

My workers.properties file under /x/y/apache2/conf/workers.properties has

```
worker.list= ww
worker.ww.type=ajp13
worker.ww.port=12000
worker.ww.host=www.abc.com
```

I'm new to tcServer (and tomcat) and I don't know what changes I have to make in server.xml on tcServer to get this to work with Apache.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the AJP connector block in server.xml - by default it's the one listed with port 8009 in it. Basically all you need to do is change that to port 12000 to match your worker.

Here's a complete example of many of things you can set if needed - right now you're running a very bare-bones mod_jk setup, there are Jk* options for Apache you can tune and workers.properties.

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<!-- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" allowTrace="false"
           emptySessionPath="false" enableLookups="false"
           maxPostSize="2097152" maxSavePostSize="4096" redirectPort="443"
           scheme="http" secure="false" URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="false" xpoweredBy="false"
           useIPVHosts="false" address="127.0.0.1" backlog="10"
           bufferSize="-1" connectionTimeout="60000"
           keepAliveTimeout="60000" maxThreads="200" packetSize="8192"
           request.secret="" request.useSecret="false"
           request.shutdownEnabled="false" tcpNoDelay="true"
           tomcatAuthentication="true" />
```